# Cannot convert object of type System.String to type System.Byte[] when deserializing object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class in C# that maps *InspectionDetails* sent from a mobile app (a JSON object) to a Web API service. I recently added a property to the class to handle sending images from the mobile app. But when deserializing the JSON I get the error

**Cannot convert object of type System.String to type System.Byte[]**

My class in C# looks like this.

```
public class InspectionDetails
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> Images { get; set; }
}
```

I then attempt to deserialize the JSON as follows.

```
result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonObject); // throws error
```

An example of the JSON is as follows:

```
{"UserId":1001872,"Images":["fFCVKyfUYq72+N0M3IzaihLH0/rMDSwdbPHTXpwkQTw+Fp1NlYKvyyp0e+yIxoOOVe24Ous2ESsAfD4kIeN=="]}
```

How do I deserialize a byte array in JSON? I need to deserializethe JSON to get to the images.

Comment: you don't suppose that the code which generates the json, or a sample of a json message, might be slightly pertinent to the question you have posted?

Comment: Example JSON now added to the original post.

Comment: It looks like your `Images` string is invalid Base64.  If I do `Convert.FromBase64String("fFCVKyfUYq72+N0M3IzaihLH0/rMDSwdbPHTXpwkQTw+Fp1NlYKvyyp0e+yIxoOOVe24Ous2ESsAfD4kIeN==");` I get an exception thrown `"Invalid character in a Base-64 string."`.  How was the base64 string generated?

Comment: I truncated the image as it was far too long for a comment on here.

Comment: @dbc: You've got some strange non displaying characters in your string. If I copy your code it fails, if I copy the string from the question it decodes fine...

Comment: @Chris - Just tried copying again, I'm still getting the problem.  If the string in the question was truncated then base64 decoding could fail if the length is wrong.  And in fact removing an extra `=` from the end of the string makes it work for me.

Comment: @dbc: I can see 6 extra characters in your string. Do `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` on your string and you'll see in the middle some extra bytes: `226 128 140 226 128 139`.

Comment: @DomBurf: Your code works just fine for me. Are you sure that the code above accurately reflects what you have in your real code?

Comment: @dbc: in case you are interested I just looked up those characters and they are a zero width joiner and a zero width non-joiner... Was the text split on your screen? Might be that your browser added in some extra characters for fun...

Comment: @Chris The example JSON was truncated so as to fit into a comment.

Comment: @Chris - OK, it looks like, if I recopy the string from my comment, there are encoding problems.  But I didn't do that originally, I copied it from the question because I hadn't made the comment yet.  And if I recopy from the question I still get the base64 error.  But if I run on dotnetfiddle there's no exception, rather the string is changed by round-tripping the base64 encoding: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7r8st6  Must be something strange or out of date on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work with JSON.NET 8.0.2

```
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
    };
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonObject, jsonSettings);
```

Comment: I tried to run this code and it worked... But then I ran it without passing in the settings and it still worked... Can you add some explanation of why you need that settings and in particular which of the two settings it is that you think fixed the problem?

Comment: I think this all depends what version you are working with if it "works" in both cases.  TypeNameHandling: Gets or sets how type name writing and reading is handled by the serializer. TypeNameAssemblyFormat : Gets or sets how a type name assembly is written and resolved by the serializer.